# AWS Elastic Beanstalk run Grunt task

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to run a node.js application on elastic beanstalk. I have a client which gets build by a grunt job (jade, less, concat, etc.) I excluded this folder from git

I can localy run this by `grunt buildClient` which is executed by `grunt-cli`

I added `grunt` and `grunt-cli` in my packages `dev-dependencies`

I want to run the grunt build before the application is launched, i already setup a configuration in `.ebextensions/app.config`

```
container_commands:
  01_build_client:
    command: grunt buildClient
```

I guess my cwd is `/tmp/deployment/application/`

but there is says `Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt`. I guess grunt-cli is installed, but why is this error?

i also tried putting the grunt job in the `postinstall` section of `package.json`, but this doesnt work as well.

How do i build my grunt job on a EBS instance?

Comment: found this gist: https://gist.github.com/adamalex/7189405 but results in same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running Grunt on a paas, it's best to install a local copy of grunt-cli and grunt locally in the project. That way it's always available and is the exact version you'll need. Then you run `npm install` instead of `grunt` so your `postinstall` works properly.

For example, your `package.json` might look like this:

```
"grunt": "0.4.5",
"grunt-cli": "0.1.13",
```

Comment: Does `postinstall` execute? It doesn't seem to for me

Comment: prestart, start and poststart only as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

You can first specify the path to your gruntfile using the `--gruntfile <pathToGruntfile>` option on the `grunt command`. However, you'll also need to `npm install grunt` before running this, or you'll receive the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I've just run into a similar problem whilst trying to get webpack bundilng on elastic beanstalk. I found that when elastic beanstalk runs an npm install it includes the `--production` flag. This means that you'll need to move your dev dependencies into the dependencies block.

Something else that caught me out is that eb doesn't seem to run the `postinstall` script which is really annoying! I did find that it runs the `prestart` script though.

My `package.json` file ended up looking something like this:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "prestart": "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "backbone": "^1.2.1",
    "backbone.marionette": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack": "^1.9.10",
    ...
  }
}
```