# How do I speed up an EB deploy using ebignore?

Tags: deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, node-modules

I'm deploying my app to ElasticBeanstalk. I'm using an `.ebignore` file because there are files that I do not want to check into git, but I do want deployed with the app(like application secrets, config vars, etc). The issue I'm facing is that when using an `.ebignore`, the deploy takes FOREVER. I've used the --verbose flag, and I can see that it is recursing my entire node_modules directory and skipping each file individually. When I deploy by using `.gitignore`, it becomes very fast.

Has anyone else experienced this? How do I speed up this process?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the log? What settings do you have under 'updates and deployments'?

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same. When there is only a .gitignore with `node_modules` in there it's almost instantaneous. When you add a .ebignore with `node_modules/` in it, it takes a very long time as it goes through every single file to "skip" it.

Comment: Yeah I never did figure this one out. I ended up ditching Elastic Beanstalk altogether. I wasted WAY too much time trying to get it setup. That along with random deploy failures and crazily cryptic error messages...... Ugh.

Comment: @dphaener what did you end up using instead of Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: @mirage I ended up just using my normal deployment routine. I use puppet to provision servers, and capistrano to deploy. I have recipes for those that I typically use, and it's ended up working out much better for me.

Comment: I think this passage from another stackoverflow answer may be useful in this discussion:

"... I find that eb deploy evaluates all subfolders within an excluded folder, slowing the deployment unnecessarily. I had to temporarily move node_modules elsewhere before running eb deploy to speed it up." - @edwinbs in this [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38801595/3532313)