# AWS Beanstalk | NPM on PHP Platform

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm-install, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

for my project I use AWS elasticbeanstalk. 
I choosed the AWS preconfigured plattform: "PHP".

While the deploy process it should install npm/node and run 'npm encore production' to create a production build of the javascript/vue/scss.

I am not sure how to solve this, tried to write container_commands but it didn't work. Do you guys can recommend a way to install npm "the best way" on AWS elasticbeanstalk, while deploying?

Comment: See this question, it's similar to yours and has a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273520/run-grunt-on-elasticbeanstalk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Environment Variables like:

```
packages: 
yum:
nodejs: [] 
npm: []
```

[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-packages)